# How to read SMS and Call logs of a Firefox OS phone?

Tags: sms, mozilla, firefox-os

For SMS, I have pulled the sqlite file and put it under the corresponding directory of the simulator on PC, but it didn't read. 
Is it because Mozilla hasn't provided the function of SMS on the simulator? 
What if I build the emulator myself, can it read the sms.sqlite I got from the phone? Or if the only way to read the sms is to decompress the code?

As for call logs, I have no idea where it is stored, is it mingled in the activity.sqlite?

I'm kind of lost in the Firefox OS, thanks for your help!

Comment: It might help to read the source of the [SMS app](https://github.com/mozilla-b2g/gaia/blob/master/apps/sms/index.html) that ships on device. It's plain HTML5 but uses APIs like [WebSMS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebSMS_API) and maybe [WebTelephony](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Telephony_API).

Answer (score 0):

> Powerful and dangerous APIs are **not available** to third-party apps.

Only **internal apps** can access the [WebSMS API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/WebAPI/WebSMS) and [Web Telephony API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Telephony_API) on [[image]firefox-os](/questions/tagged/firefox-os), because they are intended for system-level apps and default apps created by Mozilla/operators/OEMs.

Check the [Permissions Table for Internal (Certified) Apps (MDN)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Apps/Build/App_permissions#Internal_(Certified)_app_permissions).

Answer (score 0):

I'm developing an app to fetch SMS and other data from Firefox OS device. You can see the source code [here](https://github.com/elninosi/BackupApp-FXOS).

Comment: Link-only answers are highly discouraged here because the links may become dead in the future. I suggest you edit your answer with quotes from the sources you cite.